# Getting type error with Sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Im getting the following error and I can't figure out through the stack trace where it's erroring.

```
/Users/rahulsharma/Desktop/Jobletics/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:298
      this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes)
                               ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at module.exports.Sequelize.import (/Users/ra/Desktop/Js/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:298:32)
    at db.sequelize (/Users/ra/Desktop/Js/models/index.js:14:33)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ra/Desktop/Js/models/index.js:13:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Here is the git:

https://github.com/rahul1346/jb

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`business_model.js` is an empty file.